# Не выводит Mysql базу через PHp

Tags: php

В чем моя ошибка ? не выводит Mysql базу через PHp

```
<?php
// ваш адрес где находится, хостится ваша база данных
$sdd_db_host='localhost';
// Имя базы данных с которой вы хотите работать, так как их может быть множество
$sdd_db_name='ris2014';
// логин доступ к базе данных
$sdd_db_user='root';
// пароль доступа к базе данных
$sdd_db_pass='';
// устанавливаем связь с сервером
@mysql_connect($sdd_db_licalhost,$sdd_db_root,$sdd_db_" ");
// переключаемся на нужную нам базу данных
@mysql_select_db($sdd_db_ris2014);
// делаем выборку из таблицы
$result=mysql_query('$sql = "SELECT * FROM `reestr` LIMIT 0, 30');
// берем результаты из каждой строки
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ // выводим данные
  echo '<p>Запись id='.$row['id'].'. Текст: '.$row['text'].'</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: удалите @ и почитайте сообщения об ошибках

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// устанавливаем связь с сервером
@mysql_connect($sdd_db_licalhost,$sdd_db_root,$sdd_db_" ");
// переключаемся на нужную нам базу данных
@mysql_select_db($sdd_db_ris2014);
```

1. переменные `$sdd_db_licalhost`, `$sdd_db_root`, `$sdd_db_ris2014` не определены

   $sdd_db_" "
2. в этом выражении синтаксическая ошибка